# Failed to open stream no such file or directory. php

Tags: php, php-include

I've a file `Profile.php` which includes `Profile_Control.php` and the `profile_control` includes `Profile_Model.php` . Every things works fine till here.

I've another script named `Upload.php` from which data gets uploaded. This Upload.php also includes `Profile_Control.php` and as you know `Profile_Control` includes `Profile_Model.php`.Now I dont know why it is giving such an error.When the Profile.php loads it works fine but when I upload the data it says

```
Warning: include(../Model/Profile_Model.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\php\gagster\Control\Profile_Control.php on line 4
```

In Upload.php :

```
include_once("../../Control/Profile_Control.php");
```

In Profile.php :

```
include_once("../Control/Profile_Control.php");
```

In Profile_Control.php:

```
include_once("../Model/Profile_Model.php");
```

Document Structure:

```
 +-Control/
 |  |    
 |  +---- Profile_Control.php
 |
 +-Model/
 |  |
 |  +---- Profile_Model.php
 |
 +-Other/
    |
    +-- Upload/
           |
           +---- Upload.php
```

Comment: One often runs into this error, and to quickly troubleshoot it, follow these steps : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the php `file_exists()` function to make sure that file is included if it is than do your stuff

```
if (file_exists($filename)) {
    echo "The file $filename exists";
} else {
    echo "The file $filename does not exist";
}
```

and use the

```
defined('root') ? null : define('root', "url of your site "  );
```

than

```
include_once(root."rest of address");
```

Comment: Yes - this will raise an error but you are not attempting to answer the actual question.

Comment: @Lix i think now it will help the user

Comment: thnx for the reply but can you tell me why it works perfect when the file is included in `Profile.php` and not works when it is included the second time in `Upload.php`

Comment: @Mj1992 its looks like that your file is in different place

Comment: There is now a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 8):

Instead of using relative paths (`../`), why don't you try giving absolute paths relative to your `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` location.  I usually define a constant to help with readability -

```
define('_root',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);

include(_root.'/Control/Profile_Control.php');
```

Now you can place the same line of code in each file you want to include `Profile_Control.php` in.

[user1280616](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12445259/558021) also makes a valid point with regard to testing the existence of a file prior to including it.  Perhaps you should consider implementing that as well.

Comment: While the answer marked at correct is helpful I must say it was this answer that solved my problem. I tried both absolute and relative paths and both failed without first getting the document root and using that in the path.

Comment: There is now a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507